# ExtJS - Provide url to web start command

Tags: extjs

I would like to use command

```
sencha web -port 3888 start
```

But how can I point to a specified url, for example:

```
http://localhost/WebContent/My.cgi?lang=en&test=true
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a configuration for running a server that uses the build-folder as the content base (thus "stage").

Your question should easily be answered with the help of the webpack documentation, i.e. config options.

package.json

```
"scripts": [
    "stage": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.prod.config.js --open",
]
```

webpack.prod.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    devServer: {
        "contentBase": "./build/production/conjoon",
        "compress": false,
        "hot": true,
        "port": 9001,
        "publicPath": "/"
    }
};
```

you might want to look into the "publicPath" config.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use the server you can map the path like this:

```
sencha web -p 3888 start -m "c:/WebContent/"
sencha web -p 3888 start -m "../../WebContent/"
```